# "How do I get to the station?" "How do you get to the station?"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When you ask a passer-by for directions, which would be appropriate?

"How do I get to the station?"

"How can I get to the station?"

"How do you get to the station?"

"How can you get to the station?"

I'm often confused whether to use "I" or "you", "do" or "can".

Answer (score 1):

In BrE:

"Could you tell me how to get to the station?" is colloquial and unimpeachable.

"How do I get to the station?" is colloquial.

"How do you get to the station?" - though also colloquial - slightly suggests the other person sometimes *goes* to the station, which perhaps they don't.

"How *can* I get to the station..." needs e.g. "...with my feet tied together?"

"How can *you*..." needs something similar.

**"How does one get to the station?"** is perfect but - alas! - too old-fashioned to use. (So is 'Alas'.)

Answer (score 0):

In AmE, they are used interchangeably. However, you will most likely hear example 2 and 3 used in AmE.